# How to refer to a variable that is inside one structure and this structure is initialized as a pointer in another structure?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
typedef struct ClientDet {
    char *name;
    int number; 
} ClientDet;

typedef struct ServerReqs {
    char *authVal;
    int noOfReq;
    ClientDet *client;
} ServerReqs;
```

From the code given above, I am trying to initialize `name` inside `ClientDet` using a pointer to the `struct ServerReqs`. But when I try the below strategies I get a seg fault or compilation error.

```
ServerReqs *svr;
svr->client->name = "ABC"; // Returns a seg fault
```

```
ServerReqs *svr;
*svr.client->name = "ABC"; // Results in a compilation error: "client not a member of the structure"
```

I am little confused about working of pointers here. Why does these do not work? and

What is the correct way to refer and initialize variables in the `ClientDet` structure from the `ServerReq` structure in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is only a pointer and it does not have any memory allocated for the actual object. You need to allocate the memory for both structures.

```
ServerReqs* svr;
srv = malloc(sizeof(*srv));
srv -> client = malloc(sizeof(*srv->client));
```

and then you can dereference it

`svr -> client -> name = "aaa";` or `(*svr).client->name = "aaaa"`

You must check if allocation did not fail. (Omitted for example clarity)

Answer (score 0):

First note that `svr->client->name = "ABC";` is the same as `(*svr).client->name = "ABC";` but `*svr.client->name = "ABC";` is incorrect because `.` has a higher precedence than unary `*`.

Regarding the segmentation fault, you do not initialize the pointer `svr` to point to an actual `ServerReqs` object, allocated or defined as a global or local object. `svr` is uninitialized, dereferencing it has undefined behavior. Furthermore, once you intialize `svr` for example as `ServerReqs s; svr = &s;` you must also ensure that `svr->client` is a valid pointer to a `ClientDet` object before setting the `name` member to point to the `"ABC"` string constant.

`typedef` defines a type, not an actual object.

Here is a modified version:

```
    ClientDet myclient = { NULL, -1 };
    ServerReqs myserver = { NULL, 0, &myclient };
    
    ServerReqs *svr = &myserver;
    
    svr->client->name = "ABC"; // sets myclient.name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ServerReqs* svr;
svr->client->name = "ABC";
```

Is correct. The problem is that `svr->client->name` is a pointer but it doesn't have any memory. Means no memory is allocated for `srv->client->name`. So, change the struct definition to:

```
typedef struct ClientDet {
    char name[<Anything enough>];
    int number; 
} ClientDet;
```

Also, does `srv->client` have memory allocated to it? And does `srv` itself have any allocated memory? If not, which seems to be the case:

```
srv = malloc(sizeof(ServerReqs));
srv->client = malloc(sizeof(ClientDet));
```

Or if you want to point to a variable in the stack:

```
ServerReqs t_srv;
ClientDet t_cl;
ServerReqs *srv = &t_srv;
srv->client = &t_cl;
```